# How to query a XML field which is not well formed?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The below xml belongs to a xml column AuditData. I want to query all records having 'Blondie' in it.

```
<AuditText Username="Blondie" CustomerGUID="xxxxxxxxxx3C4B35821FC0" IPAddress="xx.xxx.xxx.xx" />
```

I'm trying this query which is not working...

```
select top 10 * from t_audit (nolock)
and AuditData.value('(/Username)[1]','varchar(max)') like 'Blondie'
```

Comment: (a) The XML you show is well-formed. So I don't understand the title of your post. (b) Never tell us that something is "not working" without telling us how it fails. It's like telling the doctor that you don't feel well without explaining the symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there are several AuditText-nodes and some of them belong to Blondie?

You *could* shred the full XML and use the table-like data to filter this with a `LIKE` in a classical `WHERE` clause. But much better was `XQuery`. Best is to use the `.nodes()` method, but you may use `.query()` or even `.value()` too.

In this example I added a root node and several test nodes:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<root>
<AuditText Username="Blondie" CustomerGUID="xxxxxxxxxx3C4B35821FC0" IPAddress="xx.xxx.xxx.xx" />
<AuditText Username="Test1" CustomerGUID="xxxxxxxxxx11111111" IPAddress="xx.xxx.111.11" />
<AuditText Username="Blondie" CustomerGUID="xxxxxxxxxx3C4B35821FC0" IPAddress="xx.xxx.xxx.xx" />
<AuditText Username="Test2" CustomerGUID="xxxxxxxxxx222222222" IPAddress="xx.xxx.222.22" />
</root>
';

SELECT Blondie.value('@CustomerGUID','varchar(max)') AS CustomerGuid --you might set the type to "uniqueidentifier", if the value is a valid GUID
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/AuditText[@Username="Blondie"]') AS Only(Blondie);

--This is the way to insert your search string via variable
DECLARE @Username VARCHAR(100)='Test1';
SELECT MyUser.value('@CustomerGUID','varchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/AuditText[@Username=sql:variable("@Username")]') AS Only(MyUser);
```

If you are searching for rows within your AuditTable you might use `.exist()`:

```
CREATE TABLE #t_audit(ID INT IDENTITY,AuditData XML);
INSERT INTO #t_audit(AuditData) VALUES
 ('<AuditText Username="Blondie" CustomerGUID="xxxxxxxxxx3C4B35821FC0" IPAddress="xx.xxx.xxx.xx" />')
,('<AuditText Username="Blondie" CustomerGUID="xxxxxxxxxx3C4B35821FC0" IPAddress="xx.xxx.xxx.xx" />')
,('<AuditText Username="Test1" CustomerGUID="xxxxxxxxxx11111111" IPAddress="xx.xxx.111.11" />')
,('<AuditText Username="Blondie" CustomerGUID="xxxxxxxxxx3C4B35821FC0" IPAddress="xx.xxx.xxx.xx" />')
,('<AuditText Username="Test2" CustomerGUID="xxxxxxxxxx222222222" IPAddress="xx.xxx.222.22" />');


SELECT *
FROM #t_audit
WHERE AuditData.exist('AuditText[@Username="Blondie"]')=1;

--DROP TABLE #t_audit;
```

And finally, if your XML is *not well formed*, you might just filter with

```
WHERE CAST(AuditData AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Blondie%'
```

or (a bit more precisely)

```
WHERE CAST(AuditData AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '% Username="Blondie"%'
```